# How do I evaluate attribute values in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a good way to have AngularJS directives evaluate an attribute passed in as a parameter?

Here's a [simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gytU/2/) to show my problem (I recognize you could implement this behavior without a directive):

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {    
      debugger; // scope.$parent already knows the value of teacher here
      scope.sendEmail = function(){
          alert(attrs.recipient);
          //window.open("mailto:" + attrs.recipient);
      }
    }
```

I would like the directive to use the value of `teacher.email` (note that the link function has the correct value for `scope.$parent.teacher`) instead of the string `teacher.email`.

Comment: just replace attrs.recipient with scope.recipient

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @Ajay already mentioned in a comment, you can use `scope.recipient`.  This works because you created an isolate scope in your directive:

```
scope: {    
   recipient: "="
},
```

This creates a directive scope property named `recipient` which is two-way databound to a parent scope property.  Which parent property? The one defined by your attribute: `recipient="teacher.email"` – hence parent scope property `teacher.email` is bound to isolate scope property `recipient`.

If your directive will not be altering the value of `recipient`, you should probably use '@' instead of '='.  '@' gives us "one-way strings":

```
scope: {    
   recipient: "@"
},
```

You'll need to alter your HTML though:

```
<sendemail recipient="{{teacher.email}}"></sendemail>
```

In the sendEmail() function, we can still use `scope.recipient`, just like we did for '='.

---

If we use `scope: true` instead, the directive will create a "normal" child scope, rather than an isolate scope.  In the directive we would then use

```
scope.$eval(attrs.recipient)
```

to obtain the value.  This works because of the way JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.  $eval will look for property `teacher.email` and not find it on the directive child scope.  It then follows the prototype chain to the parent scope and finds it there.